# Android UI Element

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml

I want to create a list whose UI is something like this.

[image: UI Element]

I'm unable to create the same UI using two TextViews. Please help me figure out how this UI can be created using only two TextViews.

1st TextView for Name (James)
2nd TextView for Message (Take me...)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constraintLayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraintTop_topBottomOf="@id/textTitle"
        app:constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" /> 

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```